# Dirt and Kashruth

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

Does dirt (an unknown foreign object that makes the food look bad) [have a status of non-Kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16437/5), such that if it were put in a pot and boiled or [run through the dishwasher](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/07/23/surprising-dishwasher-uses_n_1690523.html?ncid=edlinkusaolp00000003#slide=1255755), it would make other things non-Kosher?

Comment: There is an idea that earth helps for kasharus. Ne'itzah (sticking a knife into hard soil 10 times,see Bais Yosef 89,and Shach 89:22)

Comment: Probably only if you think the pot that touched the dirt is now disgusting. Similarly if someone somehow made dirt into a delicacy I imagine it would be permitted. [Speculation]

Comment: @sam, That's because it is rough and can remove caked-on oils, etc., that can otherwise be difficult to remove. However, the same can theoretically be said of some hardened (but still edible) treif substance. In both cases you would want to wash off the knife before use. My question with the dirt would be - do you have to?

Comment: @DoubleAA, exactly. It's Asur to eat. Does that mean the taste of Isur can transfer?

Comment: My point was it doesnt make things worse,and do you have a source for hard treif items?

Comment: @sam, only the reasoning behind Ne'itzah.

Comment: @SethJ Not exactly. It doesn't matter about yad soledet and kashering and all other formal kashrut things. All that matters is is the current thing disgusting or not.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that would be an answer to my question. Can you throw in a source?

Comment: @SethJ I [had said](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17972/dirt-and-kashruth#comment42378_17972): Speculation. I'll look for a source bli shevua later tonight

Comment: @DoubleAA, sorry, I wasn't sure if that carried forward to your later comment or not.

Comment: @SethJ Hmm it kind of sounds my way when you see the rest of the seif that Alex quoted in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

no.  dirt is not food.  only food has kashrut status.

Comment: But it is Asur to eat.

Comment: @SethJ according to what source?

Comment: I linked to the answer in my question.

Comment: yes, i saw that too late...