# What happens when a Jew eats non-Kosher food by mistake?

Tags: halacha, food, mistakes

If non-kosher food is eaten accidentally, do you have to do anything afterward? Is some form of “purification” required? If so, what?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12169/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think the relationship between that question and this is immediately obvious. Are you referring to the part about cleaning out your mouth?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5799/

Comment: Hey @trig. Here is a perspective on your question:   http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1614932/jewish/I-Ate-Non-Kosher-Food-Now-What.htm.    And another:    http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/709029/jewish/Help-I-Ate-Something-That-Wasnt-Kosher.htm.  And still another:    http://www.myjewishlearning.com/ask_the_expert/at/Ask_the_Expert_Crime_and_Punishment.shtml

Comment: @Fred Just both cases of i ate something when i wasn't supposed to; what now? I recognize the nature of the prohibitions are different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Purification?" No. (And this kind of thinking has unfortunately lead to OCD in some people.)

Technically, if I eat a non-kosher-slaughtered chicken, that renders me "ritually impure", and I can't enter the Temple until I do a ritual bath and wait until nightfall; but those laws are generally moot with regards to the world in which we live today.

Eating non-kosher is a sin like any other sin, and follows the same atonement process. In Temple times, some severe categories of non-kosher would require a "mistaken sin" sacrifice; today we don't have sacrifices. Basically, it's feel remorse that you did it (which if it was really a mistake, you probably already have remorse) and make plans to educate yourself better so you don't make such mistakes again.

Lastly, for trivia's sake: technically, human milk is always kosher, regardless of what the human was eating; however, some have a fixation about if the mom ate non-kosher. So if a nursing Hassidic mom ate non-kosher by mistake, her rabbi *might* advise her to pump and dump for a day or so until it's out of her system. (Again -- the formal law doesn't require this.)

Comment: I don't know about you, but I'd be rather annoyed if I found out that I'd eaten treif. I'm not sure about remorse, but negative emotions in general would likely be had.