# Are the non-meat parts of a non-kosher (i.e. impure/tameh) animal ossur min haTorah

Tags: kashrut-kosher, non-kosher-species

In a [different question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/41164/is-the-blood-of-a-non-kosher-animal-forbidden-because-of-%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%93%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95) it was asked if the blood of a non-Kosher animal is forbidden under the same issur that blood from a kosher animal is forbidden. It's brought there from that Rambam that:

> ודבר מפורש בתורה שאינו חייב אלא על דם בהמה חיה ועוף בלבד, בין טמאים
>   בין טהורים
>
> It is explicitly in the Torah that the prohibition is on animal and
>   bird blood only, whether Kosher or non-Kosher

It's also brought from the Rambam that:

> ודם חגבים ודגים טמאים, אסור--משום שהוא תמצית גופן, כחלב בהמה טמאה
>
> The blood of locust and fish which aren't Kosher is forbidden -
>   because it is part of their body, like fat of a non-Kosher animal

So we see at least that blood is ossur based on the fact that it comes from a species that is ossur -- and I'm assuming min HaTorah. Would the same be true for all other parts of the animals body (like skin, bones, etc. If a person would "eat" them?) Would eating them constitute an issur min HaTorah or is it only on the meat itself and (according to this Rambam) also on the blood since both meat and blood are generally "consumable" while eating the bones, skin, etc might not be ossur min HaTorah as they are not generally eaten?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=468 It's a machloket rishonim but the sha seems to rule they are kosher

Comment: See bartenura bikurim 2, 7 וְדַם הַשֶּׁרֶץ. כְּלוֹמַר וְשָׁוֶה דַּם מְהַלְּכֵי שְׁתַּיִם לְדַם הַשֶּׁרֶץ, שֶׁאֵין חַיָּבִין עָלָיו מִשּׁוּם דָּם. וְדַוְקָא כְּשֶׁהִתְרוּ בוֹ מִשּׁוּם דָּם אֵין חַיָּבִין עַל דַּם הַשֶּׁרֶץ, אֲבָל אִם הִתְרוּ בוֹ מִשּׁוּם שֶׁרֶץ לוֹקֶה, שֶׁדַּם הַשֶּׁרֶץ כִּבְשָׂרוֹ הוּא

Comment: You must read Yabia Omer YD 8 11

Comment: @DoubleAA Why is it a *must read*?

Comment: @Yehoshua He points out that 95% of the articles/responsa you read against gelatin (all that discussion of "Chozeir veNeiur") are merely proving that gelatin is Asur according to the opinions that bones are Asur, when we actually Paskin against that opinion that bones (and hence gelatin) is totally Muttar.