# What parts of an animal, when eaten, would make one "fleishig"?

Tags: meat-and-milk

If someone eats chicken feathers or the rooster comb, or sheep's wool, would one be considered having eaten fleishig and have to wait until he could eat dairy? Similarly, can one mix these two items with dairy and eat the mix?

What part of the animal is considered in the restrictions of "basar vechalav" (meat and dairy) prohibition?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16762/759

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/i/5209.htm#7

Comment: @DoubleAA The related ref. seems to indicate that the a key factor is discernible taste. I can't say, as I have never eaten chicken feathers separately from the piece of chicken.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70023/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Gemara Chulin 114a:

> העצמות והגידים והקרנים והטלפים שבשלן בחלב פטור
>
> If he cooked bones, nerves, horns or hoofs in milk, he is not liable.

The loshon is Bedieved only. Baer Heitev SA YD 87, sk 11, in name of the Shach said that this is prohibited Miderabanan.

SA YD 87, 7:

> המבשל שליל בחלב חייב וכן האוכלו אבל המבשל שליא או עור וגידים ועצמות ועיקרי קרנים וטלפים הרכים פטור וכן האוכלם פטור: ‏
>
> The person who cooks fetus of an animal in milk, who eats it is punishable by lashing. But one who cooks placenta, or skin, nerves and bones, roots of horns and hoofs which are tender is not punishable by lashing (but it is prohibited).

We know now that bones and nerves, tenter horns and hoofs are basari miderabanan. Regarding wool, it is not tender and maybe that it is not called food and may not  be besari even miderabanan.

Eggs which are already formed, found inside the body of birds are not Besari: SA 87, 5 allows with milk

> ביצים הנמצאים בעופות, אם הם גמורות דהיינו שיש להם חלבון וחלמון -- אף על פי שהיא מעורה בגידים -- הרי זה גמורה ומותר לאכלה בחלב. אבל אם אין לה אלא חלמון -- אסור לבשלם בחלב. אבל אם אכלם בפני עצמם מותר לאכול אחריהם גבינה או חלב:‏

But Maharshal prohibits in name of Maharay.

In sayif 10, Milk found inside the stomach of a calf or a lamb, and which was inside the body a whole day is prohibited as rennet (despite that it is not really meat).